# MSAL - use two different clientid from different directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have an application that will be used by two different entities and each entity have their own Azure Active Directory.

Initially, the code I am using is:

```
var msalConfig = {
        auth: {
            clientId: '<client-id-1>'
            authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>" 
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: "localStorage",
            storeAuthStateInCookie: true
        }
    };
```

Now what I want to happen is, can I put two different client ID, and tenant ID?

I could use multiple tenant in the first AAD, but I want to limit it to only two tenants. What should be my approach here?

Comment: I've written an article on these kind of apps, it might give you some pointers: https://joonasw.net/view/best-practices-for-n-tenant-azure-ad-applications

Comment: @juunas, it seems like it but I am not using .Net. If only there's also a documentation with MSAL.js for this concern

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `Factory` pattern and create a method that will instantiate the `clientApplication` for the proper client. For example:

```
const msalConfigFoo = {
        auth: {
            clientId: '<client-id-1>'
            authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>" 
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: "localStorage",
            storeAuthStateInCookie: true
        }
    };

var msalConfigBar = {
        auth: {
            clientId: '<client-id-2>'
            authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>" 
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: "localStorage",
            storeAuthStateInCookie: true
        }
    };

function getClientApplication(clientType) {
   if (clientType == "foo") {
      return new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfigFoo);
   } else {
      return new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfigBar);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Question**: *I could use multiple tenant in the first AAD, but I want to limit it to only two tenants. What should be my approach here?*
**Answer**: if you develop a multiple-tenant AD application, you can validate "id_token" with its issuer after your users log in. For example :

```
 var msalConfig = {
        auth: {
            clientId: 'b0114608-677e-4eca-ae22-60c32e1782d9', //This is your client ID
            authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common" //This is your tenant info
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: "localStorage",
            storeAuthStateInCookie: true
        }
    };
 var graphConfig = {
        graphMeEndpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
    };

    // create a request object for login or token request calls
    // In scenarios with incremental consent, the request object can be further customized
    var requestObj = {
        scopes: ["user.read"]
    };

    var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);

    // Register Callbacks for redirect flow
    // myMSALObj.handleRedirectCallbacks(acquireTokenRedirectCallBack, acquireTokenErrorRedirectCallBack);
    myMSALObj.handleRedirectCallback(authRedirectCallBack);

    // difine issuers
    var issuers = new Array();
    issuers[0]="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/v2.0";
    issuers[1]="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/v2.0";

    function signIn() {
        myMSALObj.loginPopup(requestObj).then(idToken => {

            var issuer =String(idToken.idToken["issuer"])
            console.log(issuer) 
            if(issuers.indexOf(issuer) != -1){
                //login successfully then your users can do otherthing

            }else{

                // your users use a wrong account
            }

        }).catch(function (error) {
            //Please check the console for errors
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens)